# Why do my radiobuttons have "not in this current context" error when in my if statements?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

My radio buttons don't appear when I type them in the `if` statements it gives me:

> The name "Activity" does not appear in this current context.

(html)

```
<div class="option">
    <input id="Activity1" value="Activity1" name="Activity" checked="" type="radio" />
    <label for="Activity1">Light Activity <br />(Moderate excercise, <br /> but inactive at work)</label>
</div>
<div class="option">
    <input id="Activity2" value="Activity2" name="Activity" checked="" type="radio" />
    <label for="Activity2">Moderate Activity <br />(Intense excercise, <br /> but inactive at work)</label>
</div>
<div class="option">
    <input id="Activity3" value="Activity3" name="Activity" checked="" type="radio" />
    <label for="Activity3">Very Active <br />(Moderate excercise,<br /> active job)</label>
</div>
<div class="option">
    <input id="Activity4" value="Activity4" name="Activity" checked="" type="radio" />
    <label for="Activity4">Extremely Active <br />(Intense excercise, <br /> active job)</label>
</div>
```

---

(c#)

```
if (Activity.Activity1.checked)
{
    //initialise the activity levels
    //take uBW and aL and multiply and put sum in usercarb
    activityLevel = 11;
    UserCal = (UserBodyWeight * activityLevel);
}
else if (Activity.Activity2.checked)
{
    activityLevel = 12;
    UserCal = (UserBodyWeight * activityLevel);    
}
```

Comment: If this isn't in an asp.net page, there's no way this will work - otherwise S.Akbari's answer applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set [`runat="server"`](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_controls.asp) to make these elements programmable, add a `runat="server"` attribute to the HTML elements indicates that the element should be treated as a server control:

```
<input id="Activity1" runat="server" value="Activity1" name="Activity" checked="" type="radio" />
```

Or use `asp:RadioButton` control if you want to access it in the code behind.